# Null Pointer Exception while mocking get Entity Manager

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito, java-ee-5, junit5

given the sample two classes , I am getting a null pointer exeption while trying to mock the  getEntityManager() in the JpaController, some one with knowledge on mockito please advise.

**Product JPA Controller**

```
public class ProductjpaController extends JpaController {

    public ProductjpaController() {
        super(Product.class);
    }

    public Product create(Product product) {
        EntityManager em = null;

        try {
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(product);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
        return product;
    }
}
```

**JPA Controller**

```
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {

    EntityManagerFactory emf = null;
    Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
    final String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + getHost(dBModule) + ":" + getPort(dBModule) + "/" + database+"?useSSL=false";
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.url", url);
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.username", getUser(dBModule));
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.password", getPassword(dBModule));
    properties.put("hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name", database);
    try {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("templatePU", properties);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // strangely, this works, but the next two lines don't
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "unexpected exception", Utilities.getStackTrace(e));
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "cause of unexpected exception", Utilities.getStackTrace(e.getCause()));
    }
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}
```

Comment: We could use the stacktrace, and the attempt to mock. I cannot see any `Mock` in here.

Comment: Your question's really not very clear.  There's no actual mocking code here. 
 What are you mocking?  How are you mocking it?  Which line throws the exception?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I tried to cut a lot of pieces, out of the code not to make it ambiguous, however how you mock the getEntityManager in the scenario above

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking in terms of unit testing... what do you want to test?
If you are testing the ProductJPAController, it only makes calls to the EntityManager, and it is already tested.

Nevertheless, as JPAController uses static classes to generate the entityManager instance, it will not be easy to mock it with mockito... (Powermock will allow this, but is it really required to use it?)

The only solution I see is to spy the productJpaControllerInstance and you will have to mock the calls to:

- getEntityManager
- getTransaction (Remember to mock the calls to begin and commit methods)
- persist
- close

Returning the mocked elements to perform the test.

Hope it helps...